# How to update the list items when doing a certain command(discord.py bot)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a list of nsfw words as a json file in my discord bot folder. What I want to do is, when I type ".add (word)", the word gets added to the list. I have made this command, and it works too, since when I type that word again it gets deleted. But when I check the list from my IDE, its still the old one. Moreover, when I stop the bot and run it again, the word gets removed from memory, which makes sense.

How do I make it so that when I do the command, the list gets updated in real time? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code snippet:

```
@commands.command()
    async def add(self, ctx, word):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        file.append(word)
        await ctx.channel.send("Done.")
```

and here is my list in a json file:

```
nsfw_list =  [nsfw word, nsfw word, nsfw word...etc]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not dumping or updating the array (or list) in JSON file. So as long as bot is running that word is loaded in memory but when the bot is stopped, It is not so you need to dump the word in file to keep it saved in the list try this snippet:

```py
# make sure to import json module that ships with python

import json

@commands.command()
async def add(self, ctx, word):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    with open("filewithword.json", "r") as f:
        words_list = json.load(f)
    words_list["bad_words"].append(word)
    
    with open("filewithword.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(words_list, f, indent=4)
```

Basically, We are just loading that JSON file with bad words whenever the `.add` command is ran, appending the word in that list and finally updating the list in that JSON file.

This explanation about JSON Module may not be enough. I highly recommend reading the docs for this module, If you don't know about it.